# Detecting keypress in Ember.js v2+

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've problem with detecting keypress in ember v2.3.0. I'm beginer with ember and I try write simple component that display pressed key. But I got problem with run action and take parameters. 
Basicly I could use `this.$().on("keypress",function(){ ... });` in didRender to get keyCode but I think it's not a good practice in Ember. Could someone help me with this? Please. :)

Here is my code:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vucenomibo/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
     <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
     {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     {{my-component item=this setAction="smth"}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-component">
     <div class="app-body" {{action "smth"}} >
       Pressed: {{pressedKeyCode}}
     </div> 
  </script>
```

JS:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  actions : {

  }
});

App.MyComponentComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  didRender: function() {
    console.log(this.get('context'));
    console.log(this.get('item'));
    return this.$().attr({ tabindex: 1 }), this.$().focus();
  },
  pressedKeyCode: null,
  actions:{
    smth: function(e) {
      console.log('aaa');
      this.send('displayKey', String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    },
    displayKey: function(keyCode) {    
        this.get('item').set('pressedKeyCode', keyCode); 
    }

  }
});
```

**EDIT**
I made it like that:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qipeponiqu/1/edit?html,js,output

Can someone review it, please? I want learn best practices. :)

Comment: You can do `{{action ... parameters ... on="keypress"}}`

Comment: @nem found one of mistakes, but still I don't know how to pass the keypress event to component's action. Could You look at it, please :) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fipiwaqasu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi, in your code you have `setAction="updateKey"` but don't seem to do anything with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Ember.js guides have a section on [handling events](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/handling-events/) that should be helpful.

If you want your component to handle `keydown` you can do it like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didRender: function() {
    this.$().attr({ tabindex: 1 });
    this.$().focus();
  },
  shortcutKey: null,

  keyDown(event) {
    this.set('shortcutKey', String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
  }
});
```

See the [full Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/21b06487899d1ba235b6) for the rest, but the template is the same as yours.

Comment: Yay! Thanks so much! :) I tried with `keyDown` event but now I see that I put it in wrong place in the code.