# Ember : Close/Cancel a form using 'Esacpe' Key

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I have form and and I want to close my form with the escape key. I can't figure out how to implement it. I know I need some keyDown event or so! but where to implement and how do I make it trigger?

```
<form id = 'myform' {{action 'save' on='submit'}}>
<div class="usersgroups-headline-label admin-form-headline-label">
  {{#if page.isEdit}}Edit{{else}}Add{{/if}}{{#if page.holder.isUser}} User{{#if page.isEdit}} : {{page.oldHolder.Id}}{{#if showHolderName}} ({{page.oldHolder.Name}}){{/if}}{{/if}}{{/if}}{{#if page.holder.isGroup}} Group{{#if page.isEdit}} : {{page.oldHolder.Id}}{{/if}}{{/if}}
</div>
.
.
.
.

<div class="action-buttons">
  {{#if page.isEdit}}
    {{form-button value='Save' enabled=page.canUpdate type='submit'}}
  {{else}}
    {{form-button value='Add' enabled=page.canSave type='submit'}}
  {{/if}}
  {{form-button value='Cancel' action='cancel'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting keypress in Ember.js v2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958499/detecting-keypress-in-ember-js-v2)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress . & . http://keycodes.io - would be a start.

Comment: I gave it a shot - but my work mac actually doesn't register keyevents for the escape key... : /  https://ember-twiddle.com/5472bff823d70a03d890a64c84b79374?openFiles=components.example-form.js%2Ctemplates.components.example-form.hbs

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an addon such as [ember-keyboard](https://github.com/patience-tema-baron/ember-keyboard) which abstracts the behavior you describe. I can also recommend to take a look at [ember-modal-dialog](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) which, while not what you may look for at first glance provides similar behavior and also explains a lot on how to implement keyboard events in their own README.

If you want to handle this by hand, you should wrap your form in a component that handles the keyboard event for you, if the form is not in a component already.

Inside the form you will have to use the `didInsertElement` method to start listening for the event and the `willDestroyElement` method to stop listening when the component gets teared down.

In current Ember (~2.18) this looks something like this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.create({
    onEscapeKey: () => {},

    didInsertElement() {
        this._escapeKeyCallback = (event) => {
            if (event.key === 'Escape') {
                this.onEscapeKey();
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('keypress', this._escapeKeyCallback);
    },

    willDestroyElement() {
        window.removeEventListener('keypress', this._escapeKeyCallback);
    },
});
```

You can then use this component inside your template and use the `onEscapeKey` property to trigger an action when the escape key is pressed.

```
{{escape-key-component onEscapeKey=(action 'doSomething')}}
```